# Nested List compare values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following nested list of (Strings)

```
[['78130 00821', '98453 94494', '01-09-2016 06:01:12', '186'],    
['78298 91466', '(022)28952819', '01-09-2016 06:01:59', '2093'],    
['97424 22395', '(022)47410783', '01-09-2016 06:03:51', '1975'],    
['93427 40118', '(080)33118033', '01-09-2016 06:11:23', '1156'],    
['90087 42537', '(080)35121497', '01-09-2016 06:17:26', '573']]
```

1. I want to compare the 4th element in each sub-list with the others :
   Ex: I want to compare 186, 2093..573 and print the maximum value of each element.
2. I want to print the 2nd element of the sublist who's 4th element is the highest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [['78130 00821', '98453 94494', '01-09-2016 06:01:12', '186'],
['78298 91466', '(022)28952819', '01-09-2016 06:01:59', '2093'],
['97424 22395', '(022)47410783', '01-09-2016 06:03:51', '1975'],
['93427 40118', '(080)33118033', '01-09-2016 06:11:23', '1156'],
['90087 42537', '(080)35121497', '01-09-2016 06:17:26', '573']]


print (max(data, key=lambda x: int(x[3]))[1])
```

output:

```
(022)28952819
```

with basic for loop:

```
max = 0
for item in data:
    if int(item[3]) > max:
        max = int(item[3])
        result = item[1]

print (result)
```

output:

```
(022)28952819
```

Comment: if you can notice, the time of posting answer is almost the same, so at the time of writing my answer I did not see his ;)

Comment: You had improved your answer, now it's useful for user not used to lambda !

Comment: tnx :) I was thinking about some basic code also,because obviously the OP is the beginner :)

Comment: @DorianTurba, I just thought the same. But indeed, my post was also very shortly after the answer of Sunitha, and almost exactly the same. It just confirms that this is a very Pythonic way to solve this problem. ncica added the "traditional" for loop for those less familiar with Python, which adds something to the answer and is fine by me :-)

Comment: PS: The latter solution (using for-loop) does not work if the last column only contains negative numbers. So, in general, I would initialize with the value of the first row instead of with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` with a `key` to indicate that it should use the fourth element

```
>>> l = [['78130 00821', '98453 94494', '01-09-2016 06:01:12', '186'],    
... ['78298 91466', '(022)28952819', '01-09-2016 06:01:59', '2093'],    
... ['97424 22395', '(022)47410783', '01-09-2016 06:03:51', '1975'],    
... ['93427 40118', '(080)33118033', '01-09-2016 06:11:23', '1156'],    
... ['90087 42537', '(080)35121497', '01-09-2016 06:17:26', '573']]
>>> 
>>> max(l, key=lambda sl: int(sl[3]))
['78298 91466', '(022)28952819', '01-09-2016 06:01:59', '2093']
>>> max(l, key=lambda sl: int(sl[3]))[1]
'(022)28952819'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = [['78130 00821', '98453 94494', '01-09-2016 06:01:12', '186'],    
['78298 91466', '(022)28952819', '01-09-2016 06:01:59', '2093'],    
['97424 22395', '(022)47410783', '01-09-2016 06:03:51', '1975'],    
['93427 40118', '(080)33118033', '01-09-2016 06:11:23', '1156'],    
['90087 42537', '(080)35121497', '01-09-2016 06:17:26', '573']]

result = max(data, key=lambda x: int(x[3]))[1]
```

result:

```
'(022)28952819'
```